# building a uefi-secure boot debian-USB

Tags: debian, uefi, secure-boot

**Target:** Debian with secure boot on USB

**Some Links I base my progress on**

- [rodsbooks efi-bootloaders installation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html)
- [rodsbooks efi-bootloaders secureboot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot

**Steps so far**:

```
# download debian8.4-netinstall (official link)
wget http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.4.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso
mkdir debNet   # extract iso
bsdtar -C debNet -xf debian-8.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso


ls debNet
>autorun.inf  doc        install      pool                 README.txt
>boot         efi        install.amd  README.html          setup.exe
>css          firmware   isolinux     README.mirrors.html  tools
>debian       g2ldr      md5sum.txt   README.mirrors.txt   win32-loader.ini
>dists        g2ldr.mbr  pics         README.source
```

As described by rodsbooks,I should now

- rename `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi`
- move `shim.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`
- move `MokManager.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/`
- make some nice magic with keys and signing, tadaa, you're done.

To make an bootable USB, I take the following steps

```
sources="debNet"
outISO="debian8.4.0.modified.iso"
relative_isolinuxbin="isolinux/isolinux.bin"
xorriso -as mkisofs \
    -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/syslinux/isohdpfx.bin   \
    -c boot.cat \
    -b $relative_isolinuxbin \
    -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot \
    -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
    -o $outISO $sources
sudo dd if=debian8.4.0.modified.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

If I had any idea what I was doing before (just getting uefi to run), I would have seen that I use efi.img. So it took some time experimenting with  debNet/efi/boot to find that adding or changing of even deleting this directory does not change booting at all. (maybe deleting the directory corrupts the installation - didnt try - but not the booting)

So, I finally understood I have to change `debNet/boot/grub/efi.img`. So here's my main question so far - how do I create this efi.img for my needs?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=efi.img bs=1k count=3000
mkfs.vfat efi.img
sudo mount efi.img img_mountpoint/
```

and copying the bootloaders as described in rodsbooks does not seem to work.